# Why does the first item of my unordered list doesn't contain a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am doing the Wikipedia Viewer challenge of freecodecamp and when I am itterating through the pages that are found the first item of the list does not contain a link to the Wikiepdia page. Why is that?

JS Code:

```
function getData(){
  var search = $("#searchBar").val();
  var url = baseUrl + '/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&list=prefixsearch&psoffset=max&pssearch='+search;

$.ajax( {
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
    var html="";
    var entries = data.query.prefixsearch;
    console.log(url);
    html+="<ul class='items'>";
    for(var i=0;i<entries.length;i++){
      html+="<li><h3>"+entries[i].title+"</h3><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+entries[i].pageid+"'</a></li>";
  }

   html+="</ul>";
   $(".entries").html(html);
  }
});
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div class="entries">

</div>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, did you inspect and see ?

Comment: your <a> is missing the closing `>`, and it has no text inside.

Comment: If you break you string concatenation up across multiple lines, you'll find it easier to see, eg `html+="<li>" \n + "<h3>..</h3>" \n + "<a href=...>" + entries[i].pageid + "</a>" \n + "</li>";`  (where `\n` is a newline in the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James pointed out in comments, your code outputs `<a>` without a closing `>` and with no text.

Change:

```
html+="<li><h3>"+entries[i].title+"</h3><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+entries[i].pageid+"'</a></li>";
```

into this:

```
html+="<li><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+entries[i].pageid+"'><h3>"+entries[i].title+"</h3></a></li>";
```

---

**Full Code**

```
function getData() {
var search = $("#searchBar").val();
var url = baseUrl + '/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&list=prefixsearch&psoffset=max&pssearch=' + search;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        var html = "";
        var entries = data.query.prefixsearch;
        console.log(url);
        html += "<ul class='items'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            html+="<li><a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid="+entries[i].pageid+"'><h3>"+entries[i].title+"</h3></a></li>";
        }

        html += "</ul>";
        $(".entries").html(html);
    }
});
}
```